# Analyzer package - How to recursively search in the results of parseDartFile()

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

Currently trying to understand 'analyzer' package, because I need to analyze and edit .dart file from another file (maybe it's a terrible idea).

I think I understand how to go deep into the `childEntities` tree.
But can't understand how to search in it.

I mean, theoretically I can write a recursive search that will find me a class named "FindABetterSolution". But is there a built in method for that?

What I'm trying to do:

```
var file = parseDartFile("test.dart");
file.childEntities.forEach((SyntacticEntity entity) {
  if(entity is AstNode) {
    //then it has its own child nodes which can be AstNode-s or Tokens.
  } else if(entity is Token) {
    Token token = entity;
    print("${token.lexeme} ${token.type} ${token.runtimeType} ${token.keyword}");
    //this will output "class KEYWORD KeywordToken CLASS" for "class" in "class MyClass {"
  }
});
//I need a way to find certain functions/classes/variables/methods e.t.c.
var myClassNode = file.searchClass("MyClass", abstract: false);
var myMethod = myClassNode.searchMethod("myMethod", static: true);
var globalFunction = file.searchFunction("myFunc", returns: "bool");
```

UPD: Ok, I think I found a way to search and replace nodes. But how to insert new node after/before another?

Comment: Some code that demonstrates what you try to do might be helpful to understand what the question is about.

Comment: Added some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`file.accept()`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer/AstNode/accept.html) or [`file.visitChildren()`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer/AstNode/visitChildren.html) with a [`RecursiveAstVisitor`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer/RecursiveAstVisitor-class.html) that implements [`visitClassDeclaration`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer.dart.ast.visitor/RecursiveAstVisitor/visitClassDeclaration.html), [`visitMethodDeclaration`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer.dart.ast.visitor/RecursiveAstVisitor/visitMethodDeclaration.html), or [`visitFunctionDeclaration`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.28.0/analyzer.dart.ast.visitor/RecursiveAstVisitor/visitFunctionDeclaration.html).